# Plot subset of pd.DataFrame containing multiple values of a key

Tags: pandas, plot, seaborn

I try creating a `pd.DataFrame` out of another containing data of multiple bases (e. g. A, C, G and U<sup>1</sup> out of A, C, G, T, U<sup>1</sup> and U<sup>2</sup>).When I extract exactly one base, it works fine (first row of code), but the second returns a dataframe containing only the first matching row.

```
#import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import os

with open (os.path.join (os.environ ['HOME'], 'data.csv'), 'r') as f :
    df = pd.read_csv (f, index_col = 0, header = 0, thousands = None, decimal = '.')

g0 = df.loc [df ['base'] == 'A']
g1 = df.loc [df ['base'].keys () == df ['base'].keys ().any (['A', 'C', 'G', 'U1'])]

print ('df\n', df)
print ()
print ('g0\n', g0)
print ()
print ('g1\n', g1)

#sns.catplot (data = df, x = 'base', y = 'energy', hue = 'charge')
```

**My output:**

```
df
    environment base charge   energy  type
0          pbs    A    neg  0.34835     1
1          pbs    C    neg  0.40194     2
2          pbs    G    neg  0.34959     1
3          pbs    T    neg  0.40738     2
4          pbs   U1    neg  0.34904     2
5          pbs   U2    neg  0.40016     2
6          pbs    A    neu  0.40151     3
7          pbs    C    neu  0.34494     3
8          pbs    G    neu  0.40193     3
9          pbs    T    neu  0.34458     3
10         pbs   U1    neu  0.34646     3
11         pbs   U2    neu  0.40871     3
12         pbs    A    pos  0.34047     2
13         pbs    C    pos  0.40157     2
14         pbs    G    pos  0.34232     2
15         pbs    T    pos  0.40854     2
16         pbs   U1    pos  0.34611     2
17         pbs   U2    pos  0.34414     2

g0
    environment base charge   energy  type
0          pbs    A    neg  0.34835     1
6          pbs    A    neu  0.40151     3
12         pbs    A    pos  0.34047     2

g1
   environment base charge   energy  type
1         pbs    C    neg  0.40194     2
```

**My deesired output:**

```
df
    environment base charge   energy  type
0          pbs    A    neg  0.34835     1
1          pbs    C    neg  0.40194     2
2          pbs    G    neg  0.34959     1
3          pbs    T    neg  0.40738     2
4          pbs   U1    neg  0.34904     2
5          pbs   U2    neg  0.40016     2
6          pbs    A    neu  0.40151     3
7          pbs    C    neu  0.34494     3
8          pbs    G    neu  0.40193     3
9          pbs    T    neu  0.34458     3
10         pbs   U1    neu  0.34646     3
11         pbs   U2    neu  0.40871     3
12         pbs    A    pos  0.34047     2
13         pbs    C    pos  0.40157     2
14         pbs    G    pos  0.34232     2
15         pbs    T    pos  0.40854     2
16         pbs   U1    pos  0.34611     2
17         pbs   U2    pos  0.34414     2

g0
    environment base charge   energy  type
0          pbs    A    neg  0.34835     1
6          pbs    A    neu  0.40151     3
12         pbs    A    pos  0.34047     2

g1
   environment base charge   energy  type
0          pbs    A    neg  0.34835     1
1          pbs    C    neg  0.40194     2
2          pbs    G    neg  0.34959     1
4          pbs   U1    neg  0.34904     2
6          pbs    A    neu  0.40151     3
7          pbs    C    neu  0.34494     3
8          pbs    G    neu  0.40193     3
10         pbs   U1    neu  0.34646     3
12         pbs    A    pos  0.34047     2
13         pbs    C    pos  0.40157     2
14         pbs    G    pos  0.34232     2
16         pbs   U1    pos  0.34611     2
```

**Additional information:**
The data is stored in a `*.csv` file and the dataframes (containing *a)* all; *b)* several; *c)* some other set of the bases) are going to be plotted by several categories, e.g. charge, environment.
I'm planning to plot with `seaborn`.

**~/data.csv**:

```
,environment,base,charge,energy,type
0,pbs,A,neg,0.34835,1
1,pbs,C,neg,0.40194,2
2,pbs,G,neg,0.34959,1
3,pbs,T,neg,0.40738,2
4,pbs,U1,neg,0.34904,2
5,pbs,U2,neg,0.40016,2
6,pbs,A,neu,0.40151,3
7,pbs,C,neu,0.34494,3
8,pbs,G,neu,0.40193,3
9,pbs,T,neu,0.34458,3
10,pbs,U1,neu,0.34646,3
11,pbs,U2,neu,0.40871,3
12,pbs,A,pos,0.34047,2
13,pbs,C,pos,0.40157,2
14,pbs,G,pos,0.34232,2
15,pbs,T,pos,0.40854,2
16,pbs,U1,pos,0.34611,2
17,pbs,U2,pos,0.34414,2
```

Most of my tries creating `g1` returns either `True` or `False` or an empty dataframe.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Good answers need good questions. Have a look at [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You can edit your questions to make it easier to get help.

Comment: Do you also need the python packages installed? If so, is the version relevant/crucial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you the data helped. You can use [isin](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) as follows:

```
g1 = df.loc[df["base"].isin(["A", "C", "G", "U1"])]
print(g1)
   environment base charge  energy  type
1          pbs    A    neg   0.348     1
2          pbs    C    neg   0.402     2
3          pbs    G    neg   0.350     1
5          pbs   U1    neg   0.349     2
7          pbs    A    neu   0.402     3
8          pbs    C    neu   0.345     3
9          pbs    G    neu   0.402     3
11         pbs   U1    neu   0.346     3
13         pbs    A    pos   0.340     2
14         pbs    C    pos   0.402     2
15         pbs    G    pos   0.342     2
17         pbs   U1    pos   0.346     2
```